# Angular2 - Split i18n files per module

Tags: angular, internationalization, lazy-loading

I can't find a solution to split my i18n (.xlf) files per module. The applcation is huge and only a xlf file might be 10MB or more.

I want to split this file per module and loading them with the lazy loading of the module.

Thank you

Comment: I am sorry that I can't answer your question. Did you ever find a way?
I am not using lazy loading but I have multiple apps within one app and each app uses different set of modules (some shared with multiple apps). This allows me to have translation files for each app which are smaller as if I would have to provide a giant xlf file.